# Neo4j remove existing relationships itself during adding new relationships

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, nosql

I have a code responsible for creating new relationship between two nodes.
At first It get a two nodes by property (pk), check if such relationship between those nodes already exists and if It doesn't not, create one.

```
public void createNeo4jGraphLink(@Nonnull final String childPk, @Nonnull final String parentPk) {
    final UUID measureId = measureService.startMeasure(MeasureService.MeasureEvent.NEO_PERSIST);

    Node child = neoRepository.findOneByPk(childPk);
    Node parent = neoRepository.findOneByPk(parentPk);

    checkIfLinkingAllowed(child, parent);

    if (child.getPartOf() == null || !child.getPartOf().contains(parent)) {
        if (child.getPartOf() == null) {
            child.setPartOf(new HashSet<>());
        }
        child.getPartOf().add(parent);
        neoRepository.save(child);
    }

    measureService.fixMeasure(MeasureService.MeasureEvent.NEO_PERSIST, measureId);
}
```

I can see that number of relationships rises in db, but one moment it sharply decrease and so on.. What reason can lead to this behavior? I've tried to use @Transactional annotation, experimented with propagation and isolation of transaction and tried without transactions at all, but it all does not work. Btw I use Spring Data Neo4j repositories. Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE.
Child and parent entity' type is "Node" which is defined as a follows

```
@NodeEntity(label = "node")
public class Node {

    private String pk = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Set<Node> partOf;

    private String type;

    public Node() {
    }

    @Property(name = "pk")
    public String getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(String pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @GraphId(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Property(name = "type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Property(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Relationship(type = "PART_OF", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    public Set<Node> getPartOf() {
        return partOf;
    }

    public void setPartOf(Set<Node> partOf) {
        this.partOf = partOf;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Node node = (Node) o;

        if (!pk.equals(node.pk)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return pk.hashCode();
    }
}
```

I perform adding the relationship 1800 times, but as result have 62 relationships. Code does not throw any errors. While processing those 1800 requests, I can see in database there is any number of relationships (less then 1800), but as result only 62.

Thank you for any information

Comment: Ooh i've forgot. Code above doesn't work correctly only in multithreaded environment

Comment: Define `does not work`, also provide more information - what versions you use, your configuration, child/parent entities etc..

Comment: I've added some information. What configuration can I provide?

Comment: Your spring configuration where you enable repositories, create session factory etc..

Comment: I annoteted my Application class with SpringBootApplication, EnableTransactionManagement. And in my configurations I only declare     Bean for Neo4j datasource. Maybe I need to configure somthing else?.

Comment: Can you turn on logging and see what queries the `findOneByPk` and `repository.save`  generates?

Comment: @Query("MATCH (n:node {pk:{0}}) RETURN n;")
    Node findOneByPk(String pk);

Comment: I'll write "save" query in a few minutes

Comment: This is logged by repository.save performing  INFO 10209 [nio-1212-exec-8] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest : Thread: 34, url: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/7750, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MERGE (startNode)-[rel:`PART_OF`]->(endNode) RETURN row.relRef as ref, ID(rel) as id, row.type as type","parameters":{"rows":[{"startNodeId":10508,"relRef":-208751784,"type":"rel","endNodeId":10510}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}

Comment: I've also noticed log for "save" sometimes contains such thing: UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) 
 blabla UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MATCH (startNode)-[rel:`PART_OF`]->(endNode) DELETE rel","parameters":{"rows":[{"startNodeId":4316,"endNodeId":4387},{"startNodeId":4316,"endNodeId":4325},{"startNodeId":4316,"endNodeId":4351},{"startNodeId":4316,"endNodeId":4422},{"startNodeId":4316,"endNodeId":4414}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]} Seems like somethig went wrong